# Regular expression start with number

Tags: c#, regex

I have a string like "1 n. Of mouse 2 n. Of scanners'. I am looking for a regular expression that extracts the individual occurrences. Who can help me?

Comment: "individual occurrences"?  Please show us an example of the output you expect.

Comment: Your question is abit unclear; what exactly do you want to extract from that string?

Comment: Individual occurrences of what?  And as @0xc0de says: what have you tried?

Comment: Will the strings ever include digits that aren't part of the text you wish to extract?  E.g. is "1 n. the number 1000" valid?

Comment: I expect a list containing

1 n. of of mouse
1 n of of scanner

I tried ^ [0-9a-z] \ w * \ s $, but without success

Comment: If you need to generate regular expressions then have a look at this tool. http://txt2re.com/

Comment: in this case I expect two strings each containing "1 n. of ..."

Answer (score 2):

`\d+\D+` will match everything starting with a number up to the next digit. You can then use `Regex.Matches` to find all matches of that sort.

Quick PowerShell test:

```
PS> [regex]::matches('1 n. Of mouse 2 n. Of scanners', '\d+\D+') | select -expand Value
1 n. Of mouse
2 n. Of scanners
```

Comment: More precisely, this matches from a *number* (unsigned integer) until the next.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that you string has one or more groups composed by a number followed by "n. of" and an object and that you want to extract each object and its occurrences. Here's an example based on this format:

```
MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(
    "1 n. Of mouse 2 n. of scanners",
    @"(?<num>\d+)\s+n\.\s+of\s+(?<obj>\w+)",
    RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

foreach(Match m in matches) {
    Console.WriteLine("Match found:");
    Console.WriteLine("\tCount: {0}", m.Groups["num"]);
    Console.WriteLine("\tObject: {0}\n", m.Groups["obj"]);
}
```

And its output:

```
Match found:
  Count: 1
  Object: mouse

Match found:
  Count: 2
  Object: scanners
```

Answer (score 0):

try with this code

```
        var value = "1 n. Of mouse 2 n. Of scanners";
        var result =  value.Split().Select(p => Regex.Match(p, @"^\d+$").Value).Where(p => ! p.Equals(string.Empty)).ToList();
```

result is

1

2